# Vala Program does not compile under MSYS2 - pkg-config package not found

Tags: vala, pkg-config, msys2

I want to compile the GTK+ test program for the Vala programming language. I saved the code as main.vala and call the compiler with the command line

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 main.vala
```

But this does not work. I get the error:

```
Package gobject-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gobject-2.0' found
error: pkg-config exited with status 1
```

Why can't pkg-config find that package? When I call

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep gobject-2.0
```

I do *not* get an error, but

```
gobject-2.0     GObject - GLib type, Object, Parameter and Signal library
```

So my question is, why doesn't the program compile?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what is going on based on the information you've provided—you're probably going to have to figure it out yourself.  I'll try to include some pointers here.  A good place to start would be to set the `PKG_CONFIG_DEBUG_SPEW` environment variable…

The most likely cause is that some environment variables and/or the pkg-config being invoked are different.  It's hard to say exactly *how* they might be different, but all `valac` is doing is [invoking `pkg-config`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/codegen/valaccodecompiler.vala#n32).

In order to determine which `pkg-config` to execute, `valac` first looks for the `--pkg-config` command line option or, if that isn't present, the `PKG_CONFIG` environment variable (see [compiler/valacompiler.vala](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/compiler/valacompiler.vala) for the logic).  If that isn't present, it will just invoke `pkg-config` (that part is in [codegen/valaccodecompiler.vala](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/codegen/valaccodecompiler.vala#n51), the `Vala.CCodeCompier.compile` method).

From there, `pkg-config` takes over.  The [`pkg-config` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) explains how it searches for files; basically the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.  Again, enabling debug spew would probably be the best place to start.

Comment: I solved the problem by figuring out the pkg-config build valac used was broken.